# What kind of UI controls are available to capture distance from a certain location

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, user-controls

We need to capture user input for searching within a certain distance:-

a) find hotels within a 10 km radius
b) find pizza restaurants within a 5 km radius

Looking for suggestions on a suitable UI widget / control to capture **distance** information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[An HTML 5 range control](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.range.html), or until that's as widely supported, [the jQuery UI Slider widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) works pretty well for things like this as well, either a smooth slide or increments of 5 both work here...just depends how short the slider is, if it's short I'd go with the increments to make usability a bit easier.